# nginx operation not permitted

Tags: nginx, nfs

After last reload nginx i have error `nginx: [emerg] chown("/gypost/uploads/00", 1001) failed (1: Operation not permitted)`

```
192.168.0.91:/gypost/mail/u
                      247G   17G  218G   7% /gypost/uploads
```

it's a mounted directory

exports for this client:

```
/gypost/mail/u  192.168.0.93(rw,insecure,nohide,sync,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1003,anongid=33,no_all_squash)
```

fstab in client:

```
192.168.0.91:/gypost/mail/u     /gypost/uploads         nfs     rw,auto         1       3
```

In location nginx block:

```
upload_store /gypost/uploads/00;
```

A few days ago, it was working correctly. Where problem?

**I found the problem, why nginx could not chown. In mount point was several files with permissions 500 (do not know where they came from). But why mounting occur under wrong user, i did not understand (but it does not matter for me).**

Comment: fstab config `192.168.0.91:/gypost/mail/u     /gypost/uploads         nfs     rw,auto         1       3`

Comment: mounting on .93 (where installed nginx) occurs under the wrong user, but exports in .91 set correctly. `1003` it's uid of wrong user(`anonuid=1003` for local user, or no?), but i tried set `anonuid` of user on .93, result is similar. Sorry for my english)

Comment: I have 1 more export line `/gypost/mail/u  192.168.0.92(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1003,anongid=33,all_squash)`, it work correctly. I tried use similar options for .93, but mounting again for wrong user, pls help me)